# Why does "docker-compose" and "docker run" run in different containers

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I used `docker run -it seafileltd/seafile-mc:7.1.4 /bin/bash` to build a seafile container and it worked fine. but when I run it with the following `docker-compose.yaml`, things are a little different.

```
version: '2.0'
services:
  seafile:
    image: seafileltd/seafile-mc:7.1.4
    container_name: seafile
    ports:
      - "80:80"
```

docker-compose a few more directories and as follows

docker-compose：

```
[root@felix mmm]# docker exec -it seafile bash
root@6ffb38b7058d:/opt/seafile# ls /shared/
logs  nginx  seafile
```

docker run：

```
[root@felix mmm]# docker run -it seafileltd/seafile-mc:7.1.4 /bin/bash
root@b919cfbb1224:/opt/seafile# ls /shared
ls: cannot access '/shared': No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run `docker run` in your example you don't run the container's default command, you run bin/bash instead.

By default, the seafile-mc container runs `/scripts/start.py` when the container starts and that process writes files to the `/opt` folder.

When you run `docker run -it seafileltd/seafile-mc:7.1.4 /bin/bash` you're running `/bin/bash` instead of `/scripts/start.py`. So that process isn't running and writing files to opt.

I assume you ran `docker-compose up` or `docker-compose run seafile` which ran `/scripts/start.py` and then wrote to the opt folder.

If you'd like a docker-compose command that is the equivalent of the docker command you ran, you could run `docker-compose run seafile /bin/bash` and you'd get the same result as your docker run command.

Comment: I got it, Thank you very much.